# Self-signed Certificate on Android with Spongy Castle

Tags: android, rsa, digital-signature, bouncycastle, x509

I'm creating a self signed certificate on Android using SpongyCastle.

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption").setProvider("BC").build(keyPair.getPrivate());
```

Everything works, but the SHA256WithRSAEncryption generate PKCS#1.5 Padding. I don't want that padding.  I've tried with "SHA256withRSA/PSS" as suggested by an user, but that alg cannot be found on Spongy. Does anyone know wich other kind of signature alg can I use with SpongyCastle?

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the algorithm to have RSA-PSS padding with SpongyCastle is "SHA256WITHRSAANDMGF1"